# Draw box until the price touch

Tags: pine-script

[image]

```
OBS = box.new(left=bar_index[2], top=high[2], right=bar_index + 1, bottom=low[2], bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 70), border_width=0, extend=extend.right) box.set_extend(id=OBS[1], extend=extend.none)
```

Please draw this box long until the price reaches then stop! Sorry my English, it so bad! I hope you understand! Thanks you much!

Comment: Please provide your code, this might help you to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OBS = box.new(left=bar_index[2], top=high[2],
         right=bar_index + 1, bottom=low[2],
         bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 70),
         border_width=0, extend=extend.right)
        box.set_extend(id=OBS[1], extend=extend.none)